# When Session Cookies Expire Using cURL

Tags: php, curl, cookies, session-cookies

Usually, when using a browser, session cookies expire when browser window closed.

But when using (php) cURL (and set `COOKIE_FILE` and `COOKIE_JAR` options), how long do they keep alive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies):

> **session cookie** [...] is deleted when the client shuts down, because it didn't specify an Expires or Max-Age directive. However, web browsers may use **session restoring**, which makes most session cookies permanent, as if the browser was never closed.

According to the [documentation of `curl_setopt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) function:

> By default, **libcurl always stores and loads all cookies, independent if they are session cookies or not.** Session cookies are cookies without expiry date and they are meant to be alive and existing for this "session" only.

If you save a cookie in a specified file with

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://stackoverflow.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt');
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Then, from the client perspective, the session will be active as long as `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` is set with the right cookie. This is a choice of your script.

Comment: I think session cookies expire on curl_close($ch);

Comment: @Entretoize but the documentation of the [curl_setopt function](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) is different from what you think.